# Can anyone read Seal Script? I’m completely stuck

Tags: seal

I have a wonderful print that I inherited that has two seals on it. I am completely at a loss on how to find out what artist they are referring to.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

- 㥁(德)不在遠 (*virtue is not far*)
- 陽春煙景 (*a warm spring and misty/foggy scenery*, meaning *beautiful scenery*)

I don't believe these are artist names.

Comment: i suspected the first character is 㑹 (without bottom component 日); instead of 德. so, the seal is "㑹心不在遠".

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 「㑹」應該是「會」的異體吧。。。我個人沒看過無「曰」部的「會」字，這種結構也不符合字源（「會」的義符本爲「合」，而「合」的「口」部後變成「曰」）。

Comment: that's why i say "suspected" :)

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 do you think there's an artist name in these seals?

Comment: no lah, treat them as artist's "declaration"